# Using structures in C

Tags: c

I have two structures-

```
typedef struct Element
 {
  int a;
 }Element;

typedef struct List
 {
  Element * E;
 }List;
```

How can I add elements in the array E?I am trying to do this but this is not working-

```
List list;
list.E=calloc(5,sizeof(int));
for(i=0;i<5;i++) 
  (list.E+i)->a=2;
```

What is wrong in this??

Comment: Why `sizeof(int)`?  You want to allocate `Element`s, not `int`s. Also, `calloc` is unnecessary as you immediately want to initialize all of the `a` members.

Comment: Also, don't use that `typedef struct Name {} Name;`. `typedef struct {} Name;` is enough.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat not if you want to declare a variable using `struct Name name;`. But the `typedef` is pretty much pointless in that case of course.

Comment: amongst other things, the code is scrambling the name space by naming variables the same name as the struct.  This leads to confusion, maintenance nightmares, and is a very bad programming practice.  Suggest not using 'typedef' and applying related changes

Comment: the code should always check the returned value from calloc(and family) to assure the operation was successful.  As the code is written, if calloc fails, the pointer to the allocated memory will be lost, resulting in a memory leak

Comment: @EdS. actually I never find situations where `calloc` is needed and in fact I believe that it might hide a bug in the code.

Comment: @iharob: Usually, no, but it does come up.  Part of my work is in the realm of image processing and analysis.  Zeroed buffers can be useful, and some libraries require that you pass one in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
List list;
/* you dont need calloc at all here */
list.E = malloc(5 * sizeof(Element));
if (list.E != NULL) /* check that malloc succeeded before dereferencing the pointer */
{
    for (i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++) 
        list.E[i].a = 2;
}
```

you need to allocate `5 * sizeof(Element)` bytes in order to store 5 instances of the `struct Element`, and then to access the element you just need the array subscript operator `[]`.

Note that, `sizeof(Eelement) != sizeof(int)`, and that's why your program was not working.

Also, the way your are indexing your array is confusing, the way I show in this answer I think is very easy to follow.